# inserting checkbox values to database

Tags: php

I have a php form with some textbox and checkboxes which is connected to a database
I want to enter all the details into the database from the form.All the textbox values are getting entered except the checkbox values.I have a single column in my table for entering the checkbox values and the column name is URLID.I want to enter all the selected checkbox(URLID)values to that single column only ,separated by commas.I have attached the codings used.can anyone find the error and correct me?
NOTE: (The URLID values in the form is brought from the previous php page.those codings are also included.need not care about it)

```
URLID[]:
<BR><?php
$query  = "SELECT URLID FROM webmeasurements";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $URLID  = $row[0];


   echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox_URLID[]\" value=\"$row[0]\" />$row[0]<br />"; 
   $checkbox_values = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox_URLID[]']); 

} 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$URLID='';
if(isset($_POST['URLID']))
{
 foreach ($_POST['URLID'] as $statename)
 {
   $URLID=implode(',',$statename)
  }
}
$q="insert into table (URLID) values ($URLID)";
```

Comment: where exactly should i insert it in my coding.i am not getting the output

Comment: you can put it where you are inserting the values in your database

Comment: you can use code above the insert query just before your insert query where you are sending values of your textboxes in database. then use your query and embed my check box column in your quuery. its simple

Comment: is the following insertion correct <form method="post" action=""> url<BR><?php $query= "SELECT url FROM webmeasurements"; $result = mysql_query($query); while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {$url= $row[0]; echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"url\" value=\"$row[0]\" />$row[0]<br />"; $checkbox_values = implode(',', $_POST['url']); } $url=''; if(isset($_POST['url'])) { foreach ($_POST['url'] as $statename) { $url=implode(',',$statename) } } $q="insert into table (url) values ($url)"; ?> <br>replication:<br> <input type="text" name="replication"> <br>.even then no output

Comment: should i insert something inside $URLID=''

Answer (score 0):

You **really** should separate your model from the view.  It's 2011, not 2004 ;o

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox_URLID']))
{
    // Notice the lack of '[]' here.
    $checkbox_values = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox_URLID']); 
}

$URLIDs = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $URLIDs[]  = $row[0];
}

foreach ($URLIDs as $id)
{
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_URLID[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><?php echo $id; ?><br />
<?php
 }
?>
<input type="submit"/>
```

Comment: can you tell me Where exactly should i insert it in my coding

Comment: Certainly, sir.  Put *all* of your HTML after your last ?>. Use PHP variables to store the data. Baiscally like what I did here for you.  cheers!