# connection table for overcoming the checkbox problem

Tags: php

i have a php form with text box,radiobutton and checkboxes.I have connected it to the databse , the values are  getting stored into the database except the checkbox values.I want to enter all the checkbox values into the database.I want an backend such that it links to two tables.the text box and the radio button values are to be stored in the first table and the id's of the selected checkbox values in the other table.

Comment: show the html of your form please

Comment: will you show some code?

Comment: same questions by you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062708/inserting-checkbox-values-to-database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038245/inserting-checkbox-values-to-database

Comment: [please read the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  You're gathering a lot of flags for bad questions, re-asking, odd behavior, etc.  If you keep acting like this your account will be suspended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can store only that value in database which is checked, but you can not store all value of check box with same name attribute, because by checking that checkbox, that value is proceed to next page via POST/GET

but if u want all value of check box ( multiple check box) then use name array like below

```
<form action="checkbox.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="a">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="b">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="c">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="d">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?

/* and in your checkbox.php you do this: */

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++) {
echo "<br />value $i = ".$_POST['checkbox'][$i];
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I am actually directing it ta page and from their to the database.this is just a part of my work.anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a connection table can be created (i.e A single php page connection is given to two tables of the same database)the code ia as follows. this code should be given as backend to the php page.

$dbhost  = "localhost:3306"; // usually is localhost, but if not sure, check with your hosting company, if you are with webune leave as localhost 
 $dbuser  = "root"; // change to your database password 
 $dbpass = "mysql"; // change to your database password 
 $dbname = "probe_config"; // provide your database name 
    $db_table = "mapping"; // leave this as is

$conn = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
  $select = mysql_select_db("$dbname");
//selecting the urls
$selected = $_POST['urlSelect'];

if (count($selected) > 0)
{

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($selected);$i++) {
    echo "$selected[$i] <br />";
}
```

}
$timeout=$_POST['timeout'] ;
$wait=$_POST['wait'];
$clearcache=$_POST['clearcache'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$replication=$_POST['replication'];
//inserting into the databse
$query = "INSERT INTO webmeasurementsuite (wait, timeout, clearcache, name, replication)
            values ($wait, $timeout, '$clearcache', '$name', $replication)";

if (!mysql_query($query,$conn))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else
  {
    echo "1 record added to WMS";
    $query = "SELECT wms_id FROM webmeasurementsuite ORDER BY wms_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    if (!($result=mysql_query($query,$conn)))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $id=$row['wms_id'];
        $selected = $_POST['urlSelect'];

```
if (count($selected) > 0)
{


    for ($i=0;$i<count($selected);$i++) {

        $urlentry=$urlentry.", ";
        if($i==0)
        {
            $urlentry="";
            $j++;
        }
        $urlentry=$urlentry .$selected[$i];

    }

}

echo $urlentry;
echo '<br />id='.$id;
```

//insert for the second table 
    $query= "INSERT INTO mapping(wms_Id, wm_Id) values ($id, '$urlentry')";
    if (!mysql_query($query,$conn))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Mapping Done";
            }
    }

}

mysql_close($conn);

?>